# How to bind two ObservableCollection(s) to one ListBox?

Tags: wpf

Does anybody know how to binding two ObservableCollections in one ListBox?
these two ObservableCollections both have a Property string "name" to display in the ListBox,
[image]

int the ListBox top area, will display the ObservableCollection1 items and in the ListBox bottom area I want display the ObservableCollection2 items, how to do that?

```
<ListBox x:Name="m_CtrlMediaList" Grid.Column="2" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding directorys}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding files}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the data is like:
    class ElementFile
    {
    ...
          string name (get;set;}
    ...

```
}
 class ElementDirectory
{
...
      string name (get;set;}
 ...
    public ObservableCollection<ElementDirectory> directorys { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ElementFile> files { get; set; }
...
}
```

Why can not display the "name"?

Answer (score 0):

The [composite collection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx&ei=q5ZdUNOWFOid0AW0yYHoCg&usg=AFQjCNHpTNkM6fKqs52uihQumY8Az9yb2A) is what you are looking for. [Example](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/using-composite-collection-in-c/).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.